# There's no error in soulution just while debugging

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have xamarin android project . There's no error in error list (using visual studio) just when I want to debug my soulution then it says there's error 
My error it's this

```
    Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression 
    State
    Error       The project FalHafez is missing Android SDKs required for 
    building. Double-click on this message and follow the prompts to 
    install them.           0
```

`Of course I ticked the auto install android SDK ! Can anyone help me about this problem ?

Comment: Yes,I did. but it didn't work as well.

Comment: go to Tools -> Options -> Xamarin -> Android Settings and then make sure that the "Auto Install Android SDKs" was ticked,then double clicked on the error,install it,finaly you may need to restart Visual Studio for this change to take effect